# Graphic Drivers ATI Radeon x600 for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I've been trying to find out how to install the Radeon x600 on this old laptop. I know this facts:
It's a Legacy Driver
The Kernel probably won't support it.

I'm looking to be able to have some 3D acceleration/display. I'm not really sure what to do, and/or if the Open Source (Radeon Driver) will work properly.
(Or if it's even impossible to make it happen due the driver/hardware and kernel combination)

Comment: This unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04. VTC as `not reproducible`.